# How can I get my component to read in an Angular property?

Tags: angular

I want to display a toggle button based on a property called "showID" in the Angular component. This component uses a service, and whenever the page is initialized (ngOnInit), the showID property gets set to whatever value is in the service.

I'm using a service because my app transmits data between the "input form page" and the "settings" page. The toggle buttons are used to determine which fields (like name, age, sex) will show up in the input form.

In my service, I set showID to be false. When the settings component gets loaded, it sets its OWN property called showID to be whatever the service returns. However, despite the console logging the correct value of showID, the toggle button still is "true", and I can't figure out how to get it to be false without hardcoding it.

```
export class FormService {
  showID: boolean = false;
}

// In my Settings component:
export class SettingsPage implements OnInit {
  showID: boolean;

constructor(
    private formService: FormService
  ) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.showID = this.formService.getShowID();
}

// In my Settings HTML:
<ion-toggle checked="showID" (ionChange)="changeShowID()"></ion-toggle>
```

I expect the toggle to be turned off but it is on, even when the service's value is false.

Comment: try `[checked]="showID"`

Comment: thanks!! that worked

Answer (score 0):

You're calling your service once in the OnInit, means only during component initialization. Your service might have the right value, but your variable doesn't have it because it is assigned to it only once. You would need to reassign it everytime it is changed in the way you're doing it now. You can use for the communication between components for example EventEmitters or put an Observable into your service which emits the next value when you toggle and subscribe to the Observable in your component.